# Pretty write and print string elements of a numpy ndarray (Python)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

Say we have an numpy.ndarray with numpy.str_ elements. For example, below arr is the numpy.ndarray with four numpy.str_ elements like this:

```
>>> print(arr)
['\tSTART\t  0\n'  '12345 ABCDEFG'  '1A 2B3C'  '\nE N D']
```

Is there a way I can **write** the contents of `arr` to a file *without* the `[`, `]` and *without* the `'` for each `numpy.str_` element?

That is, to **write** `arr` like this:

```
\tSTART\t  0\n12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3\nE N D
```

Also, can I **print** the elements of the `numpy` array *one element per line*? Ideally, here as well without the `[`, `]` and *without* the `'`.

That is, to **print** `arr` like this:

```
\tSTART\t  0\n
12345 ABCDEFG
1A 2B3
\nE N D
```

EDIT

(1) If try this

```
with open(resultfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(arr))
```

I get

```
['\tSTART\t  0\n'  '12345 ABCDEFG'  '1A 2B3C'  '\nE N D']
```

(2) If I try this (as suggested by GreenHawk1220's answer)

```
A = str('\n'.join(arr))
B = ''.split(A)
del B[0] 
# del B[-1] #Deletes end characters # *THIS GIVES INDEXERROR*
C = ''.join(B)
print(C)

with open(resultfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(C)
```

I get *nothing* (and nothing is writtent to the file).

Comment: Just treat it like a list of strings.  `''.join(arr)` for a single string. or file write element by element.  Regardless, the `\n` and `\t` may require special handling depending on how you want them rendered.

Comment: In python, `['\tSTART\t  0\n'  '12345 ABCDEFG'  '1A 2B3C'  '\nE N D']` and `['\tSTART\t  0\n',  '12345 ABCDEFG',  '1A 2B3C',  '\nE N D']` are very different things. I assume you mean the latter?

Comment: @Eric I do mean `['\tSTART\t  0\n'  '12345 ABCDEFG'  '1A 2B3C'  '\nE N D']`. A numpy ndarray with numpy.str_ elements. No commas.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried the `''.join(arr)` could not make it work exactly how I want it  (please see description). All the space, tab and newline characters are to remain exactly as they appear on the `arr`. If you could provide an answer with a code snippet I would be grateful.

Comment: Show what you get and explain what is wrong.  Is the issue with the array, or is it with the display of the strings.  Can you get `'\tSTART\t  0\n'` by itself to print/write as you want?

Comment: @hpaulj I edited my question better reflect my issues. Hope it helps.

Comment: That `B = ''.split(A)` line is all wrong.  May be `A.split('')`, but I'm not sure that's useful either.

Answer (score 1):

Make the array:

```
In [2]: arr = np.array(['\tSTART\t  0\n',  '12345 ABCDEFG',  '1A 2B3C',  '\nE N D'])
In [3]: 
In [3]: arr
Out[3]: 
array(['\tSTART\t  0\n', '12345 ABCDEFG', '1A 2B3C', '\nE N D'], 
      dtype='<U13')
```

Join into one string; equivalent of `''.join(arr.tolist())` (actually `''.join(list(arr))`)

```
In [4]: ''.join(arr)
Out[4]: '\tSTART\t  0\n12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C\nE N D'
```

The `print/str` representation expands on the `\n` and `\t`.

```
In [5]: print(''.join(arr))
    START     0
12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C
E N D
```

the `repr` quotes them:

```
In [6]: print(repr(''.join(arr)))
'\tSTART\t  0\n12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C\nE N D'
```

`f.write` has the same issues:

```
In [8]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
   ...:     f.write(''.join(arr))
   ...:     f.write('\n')
   ...:     
In [9]: cat test.txt
    START     0
12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C
E N D
In [10]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    ...:     f.write(repr(''.join(arr)))
    ...:     f.write('\n')
    ...:     
In [11]: cat test.txt
'\tSTART\t  0\n12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C\nE N D'
```

This isn't really a string array issue.  It's a question of how to print/write a string that contains `\n` and `\t`.

Following the comment:

```
In [18]: with open('test.txt','wb') as f:
    ...:     f.write(''.join(arr).encode('unicode_escape'))
    ...:     f.write(b'\n')
In [19]: cat test.txt
\tSTART\t  0\n12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C\nE N D
```

and for the individual strings:

```
In [21]: with open('test.txt','wb') as f:
    ...:     for s in arr:
    ...:         f.write(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
    ...:         f.write(b'\n')
    ...:         
In [22]: cat test.txt
\tSTART\t  0\n
12345 ABCDEFG
1A 2B3C
\nE N D
```

Just in case it isn't obvious, I'm using Ipython with Py3.  Py2 might be different.

The `encode` creates a bytestring with extra `\\t` etc.  `.decode` can be used to turn it back into unicode for neat printing:

```
In [6]: for s in arr: print(s.encode('unicode_escape').decode())
\tSTART\t  0\n
12345 ABCDEFG
1A 2B3C
\nE N D
```

Comment: The op might also be looking for `.encode('unicode_escape')` for repr without the quotes

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much for your complete answer. Could you please explain what the `f.write(b'\n')` does? Also, please let me know to print in the console line by line (not write)?

Comment: I'm just writing a newline to the file (`write` does not automatically do that), and since the file mode is `wb'`, I have to write a bytestring (Py3).

Comment: Then, how would the code for `print` be so that I would print the formatted elements line by line?

Comment: Thanks for the latest edit but it does not work for me. When I do `arr = np.array(['\tSTART\t  0\n',  '12345 ABCDEFG',  '1A 2B3C',  '\nE N D'])` and `for s in arr: print(s.encode('unicode_escape').decode())` I get the output in one line. Any suggestions?