# Write numpy array of numpy strings while encoding and removing all empty spaces (Python)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

Say we have an numpy.ndarray with numpy.str_ elements in Python 3. For example, below arr is the numpy.ndarray with four numpy.str_ elements like this:

```
>>> print(arr)
['\tSTART\t  0\n'  '12345 ABCDEFG'  '1A 2B3C'  '\nE N D'  '    C++    * 1']
```

I try to **write** the contents of `arr` to a file *without* the `[`, `]` and *without* the `'` for each `numpy.str_` element while at the same time remove **all** empty spaces, i.e. tabs, newlineds and all empty space characters.

That is, I try to **write** `arr` on a file like so:

```
START012345ABCDEFG1A2B3ENDC++*1
```

From my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41090088/6167676), if I do

```
with open(resultfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(tknstring).encode('unicode_escape'))
```

it removes evrything *except* the empty space characters, that is it gives:

```
START012345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3CE N D    C++    * 1
```

I know that I can remove all space characters if try something like this:

```
''.join(tknstring.split())
```

My problem is how to write the above statement to remove space characters while at the same time join the elements and apply the encode (as seen above).

Comment: I get an error if trying to write the `encoded` string to a `w` file; it has to be opened with `wb`.

Comment: If you have removed all the special characters do you still need to use the `encode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the array of strings from your previous question (and my answer):

```
arr = np.array(['\tSTART\t  0\n',  '12345 ABCDEFG',  '1A 2B3C',  '\nEN D'])
```

we can turn it into a single string with `join` (works as though it was a list of strings):

```
In [1153]: astr=''.join(arr)
In [1154]: astr
Out[1154]: '\tSTART\t  0\n12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C\nE N D'
```

With `regex` we can easily replace all 'white space' with an empty space:

```
In [1155]: import re
In [1156]: re.sub('\s','',astr)
Out[1156]: 'START012345ABCDEFG1A2B3CEND'
```

=============

The display with [] and quotes is just the standard way of displaying an array:

```
In [1157]: print(arr)
['\tSTART\t  0\n' '12345 ABCDEFG' '1A 2B3C' '\nE N D']
```

It is slightly different from the standard way of displaying a list (note the commas):

```
In [1158]: print(arr.tolist())
['\tSTART\t  0\n', '12345 ABCDEFG', '1A 2B3C', '\nE N D']
```

You might find it instructive to display the `str(arr)` and `repr(arr)` strings.  Every Python object has a way of displaying itself as a string.  Two ways actually, the `str` and the `repr`.

============

The unicode escape can be applied to the 'join' string, but it doesn't look like the `re.sub` does anything to that.  We'd have to explore the `re` docs to see if has anything about working with byte strings:

```
In [1164]: bstr=''.join(arr).encode('unicode_escape')
In [1165]: bstr
Out[1165]: b'\\tSTART\\t  0\\n12345 ABCDEFG1A 2B3C\\nE N D'
In [1166]: re.sub(b'\s',b'',bstr)
Out[1166]: b'\\tSTART\\t0\\n12345ABCDEFG1A2B3C\\nEND'
```

But if you strip out the special characters before hand, you can apply the encode after.

```
In [1168]: re.sub('\s','',astr).encode('unicode_escape')
Out[1168]: b'START012345ABCDEFG1A2B3CEND'
```

This `re.sub` also works with a plain encode:

```
In [1177]: re.sub(b'\s',b'',astr.encode())
Out[1177]: b'START012345ABCDEFG1A2B3CEND'
```

==============

`split()` also works because the default split is 'white space' (similar to `re.split('\s+',astr)`).  So these variations work:

`encode` and join with `b''`:

```
In [1180]: b''.join(astr.encode().split())
Out[1180]: b'START012345ABCDEFG1A2B3CEND'
```

With the `escape`, `split` no longer recognizes those special characters

```
In [1181]: b''.join(astr.encode('unicode_escape').split())
Out[1181]: b'\\tSTART\\t0\\n12345ABCDEFG1A2B3C\\nEND'
```

You can also encode after removing the white spaces.  You can add the `escape`, but it has no purpose now.

```
In [1183]: (''.join(astr.split())).encode()
Out[1183]: b'START012345ABCDEFG1A2B3CEND'
```

Comment: Apologies for not accepting earlier. great answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After joining all the array element, just split the resulting string by any whitespace character and re-join the obtained array:

```
''.join(''.join(tknstring).split()).encode('unicode_escape')
```